# Lists Not Saving Entry Data Tkinter

Tags: python, list, function, tkinter

I'm having a button save what's in an entry, and, for some reason, it isn't saving it properly to the list **outside** of the function, as in inside the function Submit(), it remembers the entry value just fine.
Here is the part of the function for setting up the entry:

```
Q8answer = Entry(r)
Q8answer.config(fg = "blue",bg = "white",font = ("Arial",20),)
Q8answer.place(relx = 0.5,rely = 0.5,anchor = "center")

submit = Button(r, text = "Submit THIS Answer",command = Submit)
submit.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.8, anchor = "center")
```

And this is the function called Submit():

```
def Submit():
    answers[7] = str(Q8answer.get())
    print(answers)
```

And BTW, I do globalise all the variables needed, as the other answers which are multiple choice with button questions ( answers[0] to answers[6] ), all worked and saved to the list properly.

EDIT:Heres some more context:

```
    Q8answer.place_forget()
    submit.place_forget()

    Q8answer = Entry(r)
    Q8answer.config(fg = "blue",font = ("Arial",20),)

    submit = Button(r, text = "Submit THIS Answer", command = Submit() )

    Amode = 0
    Bmode = 0
    Cmode = 0
    Dmode = 0
    Abutton.config(image = unselected)
    Bbutton.config(image = unselected)
    Cbutton.config(image = unselected)
    Dbutton.config(image = unselected)

    if mode == 1:
        if questionNumber < len(questions):
            questionNumber += 1
            if questionNumber == 8:
                Correct()
            elif questionNumber == 7:
                Abutton.place_forget()
                Bbutton.place_forget()
                Cbutton.place_forget()
                Dbutton.place_forget()

                Alabel.place_forget()
                Blabel.place_forget()
                Clabel.place_forget()
                Dlabel.place_forget()

                Number = Label(r,text = "Question " + str(questionNumber + 1))
                Number.config(fg = "blue",bg = "grey", font = ("Arial",15))
                Number.place(relx = 0.02, rely = 0.02 )

                question = questions[questionNumber]
                Question.place_forget()
                Question = Label(r,text = question)
                Question.config(fg = "blue",bg = "grey")
                Question.config(font = ("Arial",20))
                Question.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.15, anchor = "center")

                Q8answer = Entry(r)
                Q8answer.config(fg = "blue",bg = "white",font = ("Arial",20),)
                Q8answer.place(relx = 0.5,rely = 0.5,anchor = "center")

                submit = Button(r, text = "Submit THIS Answer",command = Submit)
                submit.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.8, anchor = "center")
            else:
                Q8answer.place_forget()
                submit.place_forget()
```

and after that bit at the else statement, it doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: You tell us what it doesn't do.  What *does* it do?  What does your print statement print?

Comment: What does `len(answers)` return?

Comment: It would be great to get a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: The print statement is just there to tell me whether it worked. Inside the function, it prints out the list of answers just fine, but outside, when I print it, it doesn't include number 7, the one with the entry widget.

And len(answers) returns the length of the list answers.

Comment: `command=` needs callback - it means function name without `()` - but in last code you have `command = Submit() `. It should be `command=Submit`

Comment: command `Button( comman= )` doesn't wait for click - it only inform mainloop what it has to exececute when you click button. All code after `Buttom()` is executed even before `mainloop` opens window and before you click button - so it doesn't have `answer[7]` yet. If you have to do something after click then you have to do it inside function `Submit()`

Comment: @FahimZaman I'm not quizzing you. What is the _length_ of the list answers according to `len(answers)`?

Comment: How exactly are you globalizing variables? Have you tried adding `global answers` inside your `Submit` function?

Comment: Sorry, as I had forgotten to check this post for a long time. Thanks to @furas for your comment, that was the problem. Could you put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with the command you set the button to execute.

the below code for example

```
tk.Button(..., command=submit())
```

In this code, the command submit() will be executed even before the mainloop runs, and at that instance of time, answer[7] is nowhere present.

Just change the command styling to

```
tk.Button(..., command=submit)
```

and it should work.

MOREOVER -- (Useful info)

In case of functions which expect arguments to be supplied, the lambda keyword is used like below::

```
tk.Button(..., command=lambda x: submit(x))
```